# Reusing session/context with HttpClient

Tags: java, httpclient

I am trying to reuse the session/context with HttpClient when connecting with other server (to make HttpClient use the same connection). For this I am using  a pooling connection manager and each time I create the HttpClient with this connection manager ... but it still connects to the other server with a different context/session.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are confusing connection persistence and HTTP state / session management. HTTP sessions can span across multiple connections.and usually have nothing to do with persistent connections. What you want is to re-use the CookieStore along with all the cookies it contains for all logically related HTTP exchanges. See this section of the HttpClient tutorial for more details http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html#d5e849